# how can I calculate the sum of the lower triangular in O(1)?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tUtb.png
$$M = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1&2& \vdots &n \\ 
  1&2& \cdots &n \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &n \\ 
  1&2& \cdots &n 
\end{array}} \right]$$

Imagine matrix M as above. Is there a way to calculate the sum of the lower triangular including the diagonal elements in O(1?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that that the sum of the lower triangle is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{i=1} i^2 + i $$
This is because (from the bottom row to the top row) you are adding 1 through $n$ and then add 1 through $n-1$ and then 1 through $n-2$ and so on.

This sum can be split into two famous finite series:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\sum^n_{i=1} i^2 + \sum^n_{i=1} i) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})$$.

Since this is just a equation, the sum can be calculate in $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: thank you! I didn't notice this